PyPDF does not give me the right image
I am writing a python program to merge multiple PDFs containing images into one PDF, with the option to select specific pages from PDF source files, specify the order and other things.
I'm using PyPDF to load and merge PDFs. (I also use FPDF to create PDF pages from image files but that does not seem to be relevant for this problem).
It almost always works fine.
However, for one specific source PDF it does not work. It contains two pages, and the image on the second page looks good when I open open it in a pdf viewer, but after including it into the resulting (merged) PDF it looks very "blurred". I have tried several PDF viewers, in both Linux and Windows, including acrobat, evince, qpdfview and google docs.
I don't understand how this can happen. I read the pdf with
all_pages = PdfReader(pdf_path).pages

and just add it to the new PDF document
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in all_pages:
    writer.add_page(page)`

And as said, this works great almost always. Just this particular PDF page gives me problems. Note that it is the second page of the below PDF document which is problematic.
The PDF files
the original PDF
The result after merge
I have done all kinds of experiments to see if I can figure it out. In particular, I have extracted the image with
pdf_page.images[0].image

which returns a PIL.Image  (a Pillow image). It says it is a PNG image in "L" mode (i.e. 8bit greyscale), but the original looks more like a one-bit black/white image.
If anyone have any idea how I can make the original image appear unaltered in the "merged" PDF, I would be super greatful.
This seems related, but there are no useful responses
Extract images from PDF without resampling, in python?

Super thanks for the quick answer and the fixed PDFs! I will report to pypdf.

As it turns out when I looked a little closer, there is another pdf in the same batch that has the same issue. I will see if I can fix it myself. Taking a wild guess, I would use the PIL.Image.Image.putpalette("FFFE00FD0102FCFB0300000000000000", rawmode="RGB"), but if that would not work I have to admit I don't actually know what it means to "overpatch the source colours". Would it be possible to somehow copy your solution from the fixed pdfs to the new one?

pypdf issue created: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/2660

The core issue is that the second image is less "conventional" Indexed 4 bit RGB colour format.
The image pixels have not changed, but the colour index LUT (Look Up Table) has been incorrectly interpreted and rewritten in the merge.
The Source colour "Grey" values are written as \00Octal literal strings.
14 0 obj
[/Indexed
/DeviceGray
15
(\377\376\000\375\001\002\374\373\003\000\000\000\000\000\000\000)]endobj

This has been mis-interpreted as a UTF-16 string and replaced with:
12 0 obj
[ /Indexed /DeviceGray 15 (þÿý\000\002\001ûü\000\003\000\000\000\000\000\000) ]
endobj

The nett effect is all the colours are now bit rotten. Many, but not all, will look reversed from dark to light.
The replacement will not always happen as normally we would expect the "Index" to be in <Hexidecimal Pairs> rather than octets, and the fact the first two equate to a UTF-16 BOM (\377\376) = <FFFE> is likely the cause of this odd reversed interpretation.
So perhaps this was a bug, "waiting to happen", only in such a rare combination!
In order to correct for the bug, the colours should have been read as hex.
14 0 obj
[/Indexed/DeviceGray 15<FFFE00FD0102FCFB0300000000000000>]
endobj

Then that be transferred in the merge.
Answer
One way to fix the output is to over patch with the shorter hex version.
Another would be to try export image to larger conventional 8 bits and replace with the much larger number of bytes image. Actually you may be able to alter greyscale compression and then get a smaller file.



Confusingly, the screenshots you included are only visible on my Windows-computer at work (using Chrome). On my Linux computer at home the don't work. So when I tried to do the patching at home i did know how and where to fill the missing space. Now I see that I should have added space characters before the "endobj", keeping the "A0" characters .
